# Apply CSS confined to a single react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

**Todo :**

- Apply the complete bootstrap CSS only to a single react component,without affecting others.
- However, other component depend on bootstrap, and uses bootstrap
  classes.
- Is there any trick to use both without making any changes in the classes/id used in component. And **making the CSS specific only to that component**.
  This is not be a good programming practice,  but any trick will do.

  - If its impossible, what minimal changes can I make to get it working? 
    Code is very lengthy,I cannot check each division CSS and add id now. Assuming it to be the only last possible solution.

**Scenario :**

- I have 2 components with huge code,say **Component** **A** and **B**,
- **Component A** uses  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss/style.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
- **Component B** uses
  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Both the components interfere with each-other, **If A is used, B CSS is damaged and vice-versa.**

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle to look,
Also, please first read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You use bootstrap as a global css, so things will cascade.

However, if you use webpack and want to enjoy both worlds, global css and component css, configure webpack to test *.module.css to apply css modules, and *.css to treat as global css. Some overrides will still have to be made though.

This will probably be unrealistic for such large code base for you to transform though.

A rough idea on how to implement this with webpack:

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: [/\.global/, /bootstrap/],
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: { modules: false }
      }
    ]
  })
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: [/\.global/, /bootstrap/, /node_modules/],
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: '[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

For more information, there's a large discussion and open PR at [css-modules repo](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/pull/65)

Comment: Can you mention how to do so. Which file and what changes need to be made in node modules/webpack?

Comment: Im including CSS in this way. Will it work?
Component A uses  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss/style.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Component B uses <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: No.You have to bundle all css with webpack.